# wp_query get posts existing in multiple queries

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, logic, filtering

I am trying to filter products based on select values in order to export them.
The 4 dropdown filters are: manufacturer (custom meta), instock/outofstock, quantity, category.
If the user selects more than 2 filters then I have to get the posts that satisfy all the selected filters (AND operator). I came up to a solution where I use `array_unique(array_merge(...))` for the results of the wp_queries but is not working. How I can achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
        $manufacturer_id = $_POST['manufacturer'];
        $stock = $_POST['stock'];
        $items = $_POST['items'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        
        //the query
        if($manufacturer_id > 0){
            $man_query = new WP_Query( array(
               'post_type'      => array('product'),
               'post_status'    => 'publish',
               'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'tax_query'      => array( array(
                    'taxonomy'        => 'pa_manufacturer',
                    'field'           => 'id',
                    'terms'           =>  array($manufacturer_id),
                    'operator'        => 'IN',
                ) )
            ) );
        }
        
        //stock
        if($stock != '0'){ 
            $stock_query = new WP_Query( array(
               'post_type'      => 'product',
               'post_status'    => 'publish',
               'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'meta_query' => array(
                        'key' => '_stock_status',
                        'value' => $stock
                    ),
            ) ); 
        }
        
        //items
        if($items > 0){ 
            $items_query = new WP_Query( array(
               'post_type'      => array('product'),
               'post_status'    => 'publish',
               'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'meta_query' => array(
                        'key'     => '_stock',
                        'type'    => 'numeric',
                        'value'   => $items,
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
            ) ); 
        }
        
        //category
        if($category > 0){
            $cat_query = new WP_Query( array(
               'post_type'      => array('product'),
               'post_status'    => 'publish',
               'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'tax_query' => array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                         'field'    => 'term_id',
                         'terms'     =>  array($category), 
                         'operator'  => 'IN'
                    ),
            ) ); 
        }
        $result = new WP_Query();
        $result->posts = array_unique(array_merge(
            $man_query->posts,
            $stock_query->posts,
            $items_query->posts,
            $cat_query->posts
        ), SORT_REGULAR);
        $result->post_count = count( $result->posts );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `query` args such as `meta_query` and `tax_query` by pushing them into each of their respective array.

I tried refactoring your code above to demonstrate:

```
<?php

    $manufacturer_id = $_POST['manufacturer'];
    $stock = $_POST['stock'];
    $items = $_POST['items'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];

    $tax_query = array(
        'relation'  => 'AND'
    );

    $meta_query = array(
        'relation'  => 'AND'
    );

    
    //the query
    if($manufacturer_id > 0){
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy'        => 'pa_manufacturer',
            'field'           => 'id',
            'terms'           =>  array($manufacturer_id),
            'operator'        => 'IN',
        );
    }
    
    //stock
    if($stock != '0'){ 
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key' => '_stock_status',
            'value' => $stock
        ); 
    }
    
    //items
    if($items > 0){ 
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => '_stock',
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'value'   => $items,
            'compare' => '='
        ); 
    }
    
    //category
    if($category > 0){
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
                'field'     => 'term_id',
                'terms'     =>  array($category), 
                'operator'  => 'IN'
        ); 
    }
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => array('product'),
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query'      => $tax_query,
        'meta_query'     => $meta_query
    );

    $result = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $result->have_posts() ) {
        while( $result->have_posts() ) {
            $result->the_post();
            // ...
        }
    }
    
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Learn more about it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: It looks closer to the desired result but wont it overwrite the $meta_query everytime? For example if $stock and $items have values then it will keep only $items meta_query. Right?